# How should I add search functionality to my music streaming app?

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter, baseadapter

I'm using `BaseAdapter` over here, I even tried implementing `Filterable` but it didn't work. Most of the tutorials used `ArrayAdapter<>` for search functionality. It would be helpful if anyone can suggest some simpler approch to achive search functionality.

**This is the** `res/xml/searchable.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**My Adpater class** `SCTrackAdapter.java`

```
package com.judah.songsofzion.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.judah.songsofzion.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class SCTrackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Track> mTracks;

    public SCTrackAdapter(Context context, List<Track> tracks) {
        mContext = context;
        mTracks = tracks;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mTracks.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Track track = (Track) getItem(i);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.track_list_row, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.trackImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_image);
            viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_title);
            viewHolder.durationTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_duration);
            viewHolder.descriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.track_description);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(track.getTitle());
        viewHolder.durationTextView.setText(track.getDuration());
        viewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(track.getDescription());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(track.getArtworkURL()).into(viewHolder.trackImageView);
        return view;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView trackImageView;
        TextView titleTextView;
        TextView durationTextView;
        TextView descriptionTextView;
    }

}
```

**And this is the** `main_menu.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/magnify"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

Kindly check the link provided below, I am referring this link in my case: https://github.com/aliasZadok/SongsofZion

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<Track> { ...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` methods, `ArrayAdapter` is very limited if you want to make some non trivial filtering

Comment: @pskink Will this work if I replace it with List<Track>?  Wouldn't it raise problems in my adapter's constructor?

Comment: if you replace `MatchableArrayAdapter<Track>` with `List<Track>`?

Comment: @pskink I got little confused when I saw MatchableArrayAdapter<Track> while reading you comment I didn't give much attention to the class adapter extends part. My bad! xD

Comment: for a `ListView` to work you need an adapter and custom `MatchableArrayAdapter<Track>` is what you need, just override those two methods

Comment: Thanks @pskink for the help it worked! :)

Comment: so it was easy (compared to `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter` etc), isnt it ?

Comment: yes it was! thanks once again.